# TFDS CLI is not installing through pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When I ran `tfds --version` as it is shown in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/cli), it just errors with `'tfds' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I tried installing `tensorflow-datasets` and `tfds-nightly` through pip in command prompt, which should have imported the CLI as well.

System info:

```
Device name *****
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700T @ 1.40GHz   1.39 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable)
Device ID   *****
Product ID  *****
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎28/‎2021
OS build    19044.2251
Serial number   *****
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
```

Comment: Did you make sure to include the `-q` as they say on their website? `pip install -q tfds-nightly` https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/cli

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did: `pip install -q tfds-nightly`

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by first installing tensorflow in your system using cmd prompt:

```
>pip install --upgrade pip
>pip install tensorflow   #or
>conda install tensorflow  #(if accessing cmd prompt through Anaconda Navigator)
```

Now, run these codes again in CLI(cmd prompt)

```
>env TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=1  # Disable logs on TF import
>pip install -q tfds-nightly
>tfds --version
```

Which shows the Output as below:

```
Tensorflow Datasets: 4.7.0+nightly
```

Comment: It says that `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow` when trying to install tensorflow.

Comment: Please verify the installed tensorflow and python version in your system as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations).